# how to switch screens with same id in json flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

[image]
[image]

can you help me how to make the product when i click on the category with id (eg it is id 1 ) the list of products will display the data with the same id ( ex id is 1 ) and finally when clicking on the product with id (ex is 1 ) it will show the information contained in id one and below is my json . Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is something similar to this: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Following this tutorial and customizing it for your information should work. However, you may want to do some JSON work for your data. Check out the jsonDecode dart docs: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html